# symfony2 redirectResponse

Tags: http, redirect, symfony

I would like to create redirect response with POST parameters. For example controller returning some redirecting response that making redirect on http://example.com

```
...
return new RedirectResponse('http://example.com');
...
```

Is there any way to redirect to this URL (http://example.com) and send POST parameters to this URL using RedirectResponse class ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot redirect and POST data directly on a redirection target.

If you're trying to send the data of a form post to another target, you can:

1) Change the action of the form to 'http://example.com' (here you're posting directly to that url, so you won't pass through your application (but the target site shouldn't have a CSRF protection for this to work)

2) In your controller you can create a querystring from your POST data, and append the querystring to the url (-> return new RedirectResponse( 'http://example.com?' + queryString);